# test handle login function with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my login form behavior my code is working locally the only problem is when I test the behavior of when the user is login in, I will do my best to explain my code to you so you can help me.

First here is the Axios function, it's a GET request to the API with username and password as parameters, in case of success it returns a Json body containing all infos about the user logged in

```
export default async function loginUser(username, password) {
return await axios.get(("http://localhost:8080/users/login"), {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }
}).then(r => r.data)
    .catch(function (error){
        console.log(error)
    });
```

}

Next is the form and function handleLogin

```
const [userNameState, setUserNameState] = useState("");
const [passwordState, setPasswordState] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState(false)

const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let userLogged
    // axios function call 
    await loginUser(userNameState, passwordState).then(result => {
        userLogged = result
    }).catch(function (error){console.log(error)})
    if (userLogged) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setUserInfo(userLogged)
        setAuthed(true)
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        setError(true);
    }
}
return (<div className="popup">
    <div data-testid="popup" className="popup-content">
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input data-testid="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Username" className="form-control"
                       type="text" onChange={e => setUserNameState(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input data-testid="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" className="form-control"
                       type="password" onChange={e => setPasswordState(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>                                
            <button data-testid="loginBtn" onClick={handleLogin} type={"submit"}
                    className="popup-btn-login">Login
            </button>
            {error && <p data-testid="error">password or userName incorrect</p>}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>);
```

this is my test

```
jest.mock("axios");
it("should login user", async () => {
    const userLogged = {
        "username": "test",
        "telephone": "434343434343",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "password": "11223344",
        "emailVerified": false,
        "deleted": false
    }
    await axios.get.mockResolvedValue(userLogged);
    const setAuthed = jest.fn();
    const setUserInfo = jest.fn();
    const closePopup = jest.fn();
    const {getByTestId} = render(<LoginPopUp closePopup={closePopup} setUserInfo={setUserInfo} setAuthed={setAuthed}/>)
    const userName = getByTestId("userName")
    const password = getByTestId("password")
    const loginBtn = getByTestId("loginBtn")
    await user.type(userName, "test")
    await user.type(password, "11223344")
    await user.click(loginBtn)
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(setUserInfo).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(setAuthed).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

my logic here is to see if setAuthed and setUserInfo are called which they should be when a user enters the correct username and password. I did a bit of debugging and I think the problem is here:

```
    let userLogged
    // axios function call 
    await loginUser(userNameState, passwordState).then(result => {
        userLogged = result
    }).catch(function (error){console.log(error)})
    if (userLogged) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setUserInfo(userLogged)
        setAuthed(true)}
```

the variable `userLogged` stays undefined so the result from the `loginUser` Axios function is also undefined

I'll be happy to clarify any further question
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue this is how, I made some changes to my API call function

```
export default async function loginUser(username, password) {
try{
    return await axios.get(("http://localhost:8080/users/login"), {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        params: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
    })
}catch (e){
    return null
}
```

}

my handleLogin function looks like this now:

```
....
const userLogged = await loginUser(userNameState, passwordState)
if (userLogged) {
        setUserInfo(userLogged.data)
 ...
```

then my test

```
it("should login user", async () => {
axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockUser);
//do your something in my case I render the component 
//and then populate my form and submit it 
expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last code block is the issue. You have a scope issue. The userLogged is not being set in the correct scope as you are attempting to do it inside the .then function call.

You can fix this by putting your `if(userLogged)` code inside the .then method.

## Why is this happenings?

It is easier to see when you break up what is happening. First, you await the asynchronous function `loginUser`. Next, you tell the returned `Promise` to run an anonymous function (`result => { userLogged = result }`). However, as you are passing this as an argument, the function is being evaluated in the `Promise.__proto__.then` method call, which does NOT have scope access to `userLoggged`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still no luck, now the result from the `loginUser(..).then(result=>{console.log(result)}` result is undefined.